# How to calculate confidence intervals for very small sample point estimates (percentages) for a large positive distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-distribution

I need help on breaking down a confidence limit formula in Excel. The file is calcuating confidence limits for very small point estimates from large samples and for large population that are positivelty distributed. i.e. the point estimate can never be less than zero.

The aim is to calculate confidence limits for discrepency rates (B/C) using predicted total mean of A.

A = Predicted discrepency rate (mean) = 0.004840555

B = Discrepencies = 9.68110928214714

C = Number of reports = 2000

The confidence limits are defined as follows:

95% Lower = (IF(B2>0,(CHIINV(0.975, 2 * B2) / 2)/C2,0))
= 0.00222662912049699

95% Upper = (IF(B2>0,(CHIINV(0.025, 2 * (B2+1) )/ 2)/C2,(CHIINV(0.025, 2 )/ 2)/C2))
= 0.00886971897643181

I'm struggling to understand the definition especially around '(CHIINV(0.975, 2 * B2) / 2)/C2' and
(CHIINV(0.025, 2 * (B2+1) )/ 2)/C2

I understand a chi square distribution is used due to the positive nature of the discrepecny rate and the alpha = 0.05, so the area under the right tail is =0.05/2 = 0.025 and so right of the lower limit is 1-0.025 = 0.975. But i'm unsure about the degress of freedom (df) = 2 * B2 (discrepency #) and divding chi square critical values by 2 and again by sample size. Then for the upper limit unsure why df = 2 * (B2+1) and dividng by 2 again and sample size.

Is this the correct method for calcuating the confidence intervals or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Chi-squared intervals are based on counts.  I cannot recognize a count in the value of "9.68...," suggesting you are reporting some kinds of ratios or proportions.  In that case, even application of a "correct" formula as proposed in the accepted answer can yield incorrect results.  Please explain what your actual data are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are correct 'exact' confidence intervals; they are described by [Ulm (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1093/oxfordjournals.aje.a115507).

Very briefly, he showed that for a Poisson mean $\lambda$ given an observation $x,$ the boundaries $(\lambda_L, \lambda_U)$ of the $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval are:

$$
P(\lambda_L)=\Pr(\chi^2_{2x}\le2\lambda_L)=\alpha/2
$$
$$
1-P(\lambda_U)=\Pr(\chi^2_{2(x+1)}\le2\lambda_U)=1-\alpha/2
$$
Therefore, $2\lambda_L$ is the $\alpha/2$ percentile of a $\chi^2$ variable with $2x$ degrees of freedom, and $2\lambda_U$ is the $(1-\alpha/2)$ percentile of a $\chi^2$ variable with $2(x+1)$ degrees of freedom.

In your case $x=B\approx 9.68$ and you express all of it as a rate over $C=2000$ so the latter also goes in the denominator.

Apparently Excel's `CHIINV` returns right-tailed probabilities so you have correctly swapped the $\alpha$ percentiles, and this function has been superseded. Both `CHIINV` and the new `CHISQ.INV` seem to truncate degrees of freedom to integer values. Doing the same calculations in [R](https://www.r-project.org/):

```
alpha <- .05
B <- 9.68110928214714
C <- 2000

estimate <- B/C    # This is A
> 0.004840555
lower <- qchisq(alpha/2, 2*B)/(2*C)
> 0.002288356
upper <- qchisq(1-alpha/2, 2*(B+1))/(2*C)
> 0.008987814
```

There's a further discrepancy in that you have apparently expressed $A$ as a rate *per 200,000* instead of per 2,000 so you will have to scale your confidence limits similarly (i.e. multiply by 100).

Comment: I updated the question to remove '%' symbol and not be a rate of 200,000. Noted about scalling as we want to do this. Thanks for the prompt and informative reply.